# Delayed_Jobs: rake task is running but does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, delayed-job

So, in application path I run from console:

```
rake jobs:work
```

It responses with:

```
Starting job worker
```

But, it stays empty, nothing more after this, and I'm pretty sure, that there should be logs each time delayed job started.

For example method:

```
def decline_vote
    @test=Test.find(params[:id])
    @vote=current_user.votes.find_by_test_id(@test.id)
    Test.delay.update_rating(@test,@vote)
    if @vote.positive
      @positive=true
    else
      @positive=false
    end
    @vote.delete
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{[@test, @positive]}
    end
```

And model method:

```
def self.update_rating(test,vote)
  if vote.positive
    test.update_attribute(:rating,test.rating-1)
  else
    test.update_attribute(:rating,test.rating+1)
  end
end
```

And this method doesn't work: test rating isn't updating.

Also, I tried to put an intentional error in model method, like `nil.compact!`, just to find out if method is running, nothing.

And there is SQL record:

```
SQL (66.0ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("attempts", "created_at", "failed_at", "handler", "last_error", "locked_at", "locked_by", "priority", "queue", "run_at", "updated_at")// so on
```

Comment: Try changing `update_attribute` to `update_attribute!` to force error output. `Test.delay.update_rating(@test,@vote)` will return true or false so you can get rid of the  `@vote.positive` if statement and put it in the `format.js` `@positive` place. Just out of interest :) Also `Rails.logger.info` could be your friend here.

Comment: Did you restart delayed job after changing code? Delayed job doesn't pick up changes, even in development environment.